# Task scheduling and WaitHandles

Tags: c#, .net, task, waithandle, taskfactory

I am trying to have multiple tasks consuming objects from a concurrent collection but only when a specific resource is available.

For the reason of signaling the availability of this resource, I have used a ManualResetEvent, and my task body looks like the following:

```
        while(!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            operationsLock.WaitLock();
            _token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            // dothings
        }
```

However, I have noticed that from the moment the lock is unlocked to the moment the tasks are rescheduled I might have few hundred milliseconds where the tasks can be restarted and they are not, probably because they are simply not scheduled.

I am starting the Tasks with the TaskFactory, how can I improve this behaviour? Is there a better strategy to pause Tasks while a resource is not available?

Answer (score 1):

It's too expensive to use WaitHandle in this case, because waiting task consume memory resources.
You should consume all available objects from collection in single task, and if no available items, task should be finished.

```
void ConsumingTaskBody()
{
    bool available;
    do
    {
        available = _collection.TryGetNext(out item);
        Process(item);
    }while(available);
}
```

If new item added into collection, you should check, if task already running, if not, then start new.

```
void OnNewItemAdded()
{
    if(_taskRunning) 
       return;
   StartNewConsumingTask();
}
```

You may use `ThreadPool`, without spending resources on creating new tasks.